# Vector comparison in OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am required to write an OpenCV program that detects a person wearing a certain t-shirt with a logo out of several people in the camera feed.

I can use SURF to detect the logo and HOGDescriptor to detect people.

Then I can check if the corners of the bounding box of the logo are within the corners of the rectangle that binds the person.

The corners of the logo are stored in:

```
std::vector< Point2f > scene_corners(4);
```

The corners of the rectangle surrounding the person are stored using:

```
cv::Rect r = found[i];
```

I need to make the following comparison:

```
if(scene_corners[0]>=r.tl() && scene_corners[2]<=r.br())
```

where r.tl() and r.br() are the corners of the rectangle.

**This doesn't work, I'm guessing because the operands are not compatible.** How can I do this comparison? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? It looks like you've already written the code you require. What is the goal of your "comparison"?

Comment: I'm supposed to detect people wearing a t-shirt with a certain logo. So I detect people, then I check whether the logo exists within the bounding rectangle of that person, and draw the rectangle only if that logo exists within. That "if" condition given above is not valid since the operands are of different types. I don't know how to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the `>=` operator is not implemented for `cv::Point` instances. What you can do instead is construct a `cv::Rect` representing the bounding box of the person. Then use the `Rect::contains()` method to test each of your inner points. This should meet your comparison criterion.

```
// I assume that index 0 is top-left and index 2 is bottom-right
cv::Rect person_bounds(scene_corners[0], scene_corners[2]);
if (person_bounds.contains(r.tl()) && person_bounds.contains(r.br()))
{
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Aurelius pointed out, the `>=` or `<=` operator is not implemented for `cv::Point` instances. You need to get its data out first before comparison.

You can simply use:

```
if(scene_corners[0].x>=r.tl().x && scene_corners[0].y>=r.tl().y 
    && scene_corners[2].x<=r.br().x && scene_corners[2].y<=r.br().y)
{
    // ...
}
```